# Is it possible to create a separate file in my cake php project that keeps variables for my controller?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a controller that uses same constant variables in its different functions, the variables are too many about 100. I need to keep them in a separate file and call/include the file in my controller to access them. How do i go about that and where is the best place to keep the file in my cake app/

Answer (score 0):

I would place a php file in your config folder where you set all the variables:

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
Configure::write('variableName','value');
```

and anywhere where you need these you can:

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
$variable = Configure::read('variableName');
```

Comment: Thanks, i have decided to keep the values in their own table because they are just too many